# SQL Server: Within-period averages showing same values for all groups

Tags: sql-server

From client usage data I want get usage over past week and weekly average of past 52 weeks grouped by client id. Trying the following but getting the same values for the sums and averages for all clientIDs:

```
declare @refdate date = '2019-05-06'

;with cte as (
select clientID, useCount, useDate from usageData where datediff(week, useDate, @refdate) <=52

)

select clientID,
    (select sum(useCount) from cte where datediff(week, useDate, @refdate) <= 1 and clientID=cte.clientID) as sumover1week,
    (select sum(useCount)/52 from cte where datediff(week, useDate, @refdate) <= 52 and clientID=cte.clientID) as avgover52weeks
    from cte 
    group by clientID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` and subqueries to fetch your data, group each subquery on the clientID. Join them together on the clientIDs and get your results. Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to see those who have had any sort of input in the last year, or use `JOIN` if you just want those who have had usage in the past week.

```sql
SELECT y.clientID, ISNULL(w.useCount, 0) as WeeklyCount, y.useCount/52 as YearlyAverage
FROM (
    SELECT clientID, SUM(useCount) as useCount
    FROM usageData 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(week, useDate, @refdate) <= 52
    GROUP BY clientID
) as y
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT clientID, SUM(useCount) as useCount
    FROM usageData 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(week, useDate, @refdate) <= 1
    GROUP BY clientID
) as w
   ON y.clientID = w.clientID
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove subqueries and use a case to filter out older results for `sumover1week` :

```
select 
    clientID
    ,sum(useCount*case when datediff(week, useDate, @refdate) <= 1 then 1 else 0 end)  as sumover1week,
    ,sum(useCount)/52  as avgover52weeks
from cte 
group by clientID
```